# Smach : how to launch rqt_smach?

Tags: ros-groovy, smach

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I'm studying the Smach stack on ROS Groovy (compiled from sources) and I would like to use the smach viewer but it doesn't work anymore and seems to have been replaced by rqt_smach. The problem is that the rqt_smach page doesn't explain how to use it. I tried to rosrun rqt_smach rqt_smach or rqt_smach rqt_smach.py but without any success.

Somebody knows how to make it work ?

Regards,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64519/smach-:-how-to-launch-rqt_smach-?/) by [Pandawa](https://answers.ros.org/users/5079/pandawa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-06-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK, `rqt_smach` isn't completed yet according to [this conversation](https://github.com/ros-visualization/executive_smach_visualization/issues/3#issuecomment-15092023), and I'm not sure what happened to `smach_viewer`.

I still have an interest to take over the development of `rqt_smach` but can't guarantee.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1